# Span width of window D3 Chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

How can I get the following chart to line sit flush against the left side of the browser. It seems to span all the way to the right but I want it to span the entire width of the window. For width I'm using width = window.innerWidth but that does not seem to be doing what I thought it would. You can see the chart here (https://bl.ocks.org/centem/ede5bb7d11fb80c82ad9a221c5a2b7ee)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can easily be done by setting the parent container div to `width:100%` and setting the svg width attribute to 100%. (The viewbox property ensures aspect ratio is preserved)

```js
var flowers = [{
    "name": "Hydrangia",
    "latin": "Hydrangea",
    "light": "Sun",
    "ease": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Chrysanthemum",
    "latin": "Chrysanthemum",
    "light": "Part Sun",
    "ease": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Peony",
    "latin": "Paeonia",
    "light": "Part Sun",
    "ease": -1
  },
  {
    "name": "Orchid",
    "latin": "Paeonia",
    "light": "Shade",
    "ease": -5
  },
  {
    "name": "Fern",
    "latin": "Dryopteris",
    "light": "Shade",
    "ease": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Rose",
    "latin": "Rosa",
    "light": "Sun",
    "ease": -4
  },
  {
    "name": "Tulip",
    "latin": "Tulipa",
    "light": "Sun",
    "ease": -2
  },
  {
    "name": "Daisy",
    "latin": "Bellis perennis",
    "light": "Part Sun",
    "ease": 4
  }
];

flowers.map(function(flower) {
  flower["value"] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  return flower;
});

var width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight,
  bar_width = width / flowers.length;

var flower_domain = d3.extent(flowers, function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

//test our range
//console.log(flower_domain);

var bar_height = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(flower_domain)
  .range([0, height]);

var svg = d3.select("#content").append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
  .attr("width", '100%')
  .attr("height", height);

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(flowers)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

rects
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * bar_width;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - bar_height(d["value"]);
  })
  .attr("width", bar_width)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return bar_height(d["value"]);
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

div#content>h1 {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

div#content>div.flower>* {
  margin: 0;
}

div#content>div.flower {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div#content div.flower>img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h1>My Favorite Flowers</h1>
</div>
```